# CSS Module parse failed: Unexpected token Angular 14?

Tags: angular

After ng build or ng serve I got this error:

```
./node_modules/ol/ol.css:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .ol-box {
|   box-sizing: border-box;
```

I use Angular:

```
   "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0"
```

Comment: In case this helps anyone, I had this error but the answer was not the fix. It turns out that the scss file was not imported correctly in the Angular component using styleUrls

`styleUrls: ['./myCSSfile.scss']`

It was instead added as an import in the component file.

`import 'myCSSfile.scss'`

Comment: @Simon245 nice find. This was exactly my issue. didn't notice, because my IDE collapsed all imports :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `ol.css` path inside `angular.json` styles array.

**angular.json**

```
"styles": ["node_modules/ol/ol.css"]
```

**[For More Info](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23273)**